# PHP namespace and include files

Tags: php, namespaces

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
namespace my_ns;

class dummy
{

function do_print(){echo "printing...";}    
}

$obj_dummy=new dummy();
$obj_dummy->do_print();
?>
```

This works all fine,

How ever If I put the class in a separate include file (e.g. class.dummy.php), making the code on the page look like below:

```
<?php
namespace my_ns;
include ("class.dummy.php");
$obj_dummy=new dummy();
$obj_dummy->do_print();
?>
```

I get the error message:

> Class 'my_ns\dummy' not found in ...

How can by default make sure that (all) include-files are automatically added to a given namespace?

Comment: Does the `class.dummy.php` file have the `namespace my_ns;` line in it?

Comment: Another check would be if `$obj_dummy=new \dummy();` works as expected. If it does, your class is in the global namespace.

Comment: This code *should* work as is.

Comment: @deceze I'm afraid you have to repeat the `namespace` line in all included files...

Answer (score 6):

> A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.

**[Source](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)**

Add this to your included file as well.

```
namespace my_ns;
```

After that, your code works just fine.

**[Reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)**

Comment: Just askin... If a file is to be included in several namespaces is there a work around? I suspect not and I suspect I should stop using so many includes!

Comment: @BeNice - include only once and have `use my_ns\dummy;` in the other files that you want to use it in.